# Unable to configure In-App product for USD $0.99

Tags: android, in-app

While configuring inapp products on play.google.com, I am unable to charge 0.99 USD for my inapp products. Thats because countries like Australia Canada Switzerland Denmark Japan Norway Swedan have minimum expectations on their currency. I am forced to charge 1.99 USD for my inapp product (1.27 is the minimum).

Is there a way for me to deselect these countries from the 0.99$ option ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to increase the cost to what their minimum is, for that country.